# C++ nested iterator on the same map?

Tags: c++, iterator, nested-loops

for example in Array:
I can do

```
for (int i =0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    for (int j =i; j < array.size(); j++) {
        do something 
   }
}
```

how do I do such nested style for C++ map:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it) {
    for (auto lt = it;  lt != map.end(); ++lt) {
    dosomething.
   }
}
```

am I doing right for the c++ map ?

Comment: I see nothing syntactically or semantically wrong. But it is an odd thing to do with a map, I must say.

Comment: I think something i wanna to be able to do is , for example, i have a map<string,int> mymap.   for (...outer iterator...)  {cout<<mymap.first<<endl;  for(inner iterator){ dosomething; } } when i try this on my IDE, it does not work as I expect to be.

Comment: Rather than post pseudo code and ask "is it okay", it'd be better if you asked a real question about a [mcve]. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about [ask] good questions.

Answer (score 0):

> how do I do such nested style for C++ map?

Although I don't see any particular reason to nested-iterate on **the same map**, which is weird as @StoryTeller mentioned, your provided solution does work:

```
for (auto it = map.begin(); it != map.end(); ++it)
{
    for (auto lt = it;  lt != map.end(); ++lt)
    {
        std::cout << lt->first << " : " << lt->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not criticizing but genuinely asking as a new c++ programmer, isn't that a negligible optimization?  I'm guessing end() is a constant time lookup...

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in Grammar,but a little optimization could be done.For example:

```
auto&&the_end=map.end();
for (auto it = map.begin(); it !=the_end; ++it) {
    for (auto lt = it;  lt !=the_end; ++lt) {
    dosomething.
   }
}
```

This could reduce the function call of `end()`,which may not be optimized automaticly by compiler.

And it's noteworthy that the iterator actually points to the `value_type` of `map`,which is `std::pair<const Key, T>`